# How to ensure backwards-compatibility of my Windows OpenGL application?

Tags: opengl, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I have developed a program which makes use of many of OpenGL's aspects - ranging from both rather new to deprecated functionalities, and want to ensure that it works correctly on the great majority of machines - especially on ones with outdated graphics cards.

- What is the best way to maximize the (backwards)compatibility of an OpenGL application?
- How can I test my program for compatibility with older hardware without actually having a test machine with older hardware?
- What ways are there to find the underlying causes of the issues which may be encountered during compatibility testing?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to maximize the (backwards)compatibility of an OpenGL application?

Define "compatibility"? If you want an application to run on as much hardware as possible, then you basically have to give up on shaders entirely and stick to about GL 1.4. The main confounding issue here are Intel driver bugs; many pieces of older Intel hardware will *claim* support for GL 2.0 or 2.1, but they have innumerable failings in this support.

> How can I test my program for compatibility with older hardware without actually having a test machine with older hardware?

You don't. Compatibility with old hardware is about more than just sticking to a standard. It's about making sure that your program doesn't encounter driver bugs. And the only way to do that is to actually test on the hardware of interest.

> What ways are there to find the underlying causes of the issues which may be encountered during compatibility testing?

Test the same code on recent hardware. If it has the same failures, then the problem is likely in your code. If it works fine on recent hardware but fails on older stuff, then the problem is almost certainly a driver bug with old hardware drivers.

Develop a workaround.

Comment: Regarding the "old hardware and drivers" issue I'd like to add, that many graphics developers keep a huge stockpile of old and outdated graphics cards around. E.g. my collection reaches back to GeForce 2 and Radeon 9500 with one model of each major GPU release inbetween. However I no longer develop for anything below shader model 3 these days.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best way to maximize the backwards compatibility and to get a powerful tool on tracking down target machine's functionality (imho) is to use something like [GLEW: The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library](http://glew.sourceforge.net). It will load OpenGL version-specific functions for you and you can test if they are supported by user's system (or, more correctly, by video drivers).
This library is very simple in use, it is well documented and you can google a lot of examples.
So if target machine doesn't have some new opengl functions, you load module named "opengl_old.cpp" (for example), or if it don't have some functionality which is already deprecated (like *glBegin()*, *glEnd()*), you'd better go on with "opengl_new.cpp".

Basically the most changes are done in OpenGL 3.0 (and furthermore 3.3) with shaders introduced as the only non-deprecated graphics pipeline, so you can make two opengl modules in your program: one for OpenGL 1&2 and one for OpenGL 3&4. At least I solved this problem in this way in my own code.

To test some functionality you can specify concrete version of OpenGL API to be loaded, when creating context.

Comment: Shaders have been a core OpenGL feature since 2.0.

Comment: Nicol Bolas, thank you! I've corrected my answer to be more precise about what I mean